# Wrap RDBMS with LDAP service

Tags: ldap, rdbms, openldap

All,

In my product, we manage the user data in RDBMS (postgres). However, we got an requirement to make those data available over LDAP protocol.

I have explored the OpenLDAP's [backend](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html)-sql option. However, I found there is an requirement that the primary key used to identify the user records should be of type Integer. However, In my product, we use GUID (instead of integer) as primary key.

So, I am wondering

1) Is there is a option to get OpenLDAP's backend-sql work using GUID as primary key.

(OR)

2) Any other opensource alternative to achieve my requirement.

Thanks